# How to pass Wordpress Json in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, wordpress

Hi guy i'm very new in angularjs and ionic.

I need to show the get json into html page.

How i can do that?

```
    custom_fields: {
main_image: [
"11104,11102,11103"
],
image_backgrounds: [
null
],
videos_backgrounds: [
null
],
frontpage_listing_categories: [
null
],
geolocation_lat: [
"46.4090966"
],
```

This is my json return request.

How i can show on html for example : geolocation_lat?

I try to read documentation but i not understand.

Thank you

UPDATE:

HTML

```
<ion-view title="{{post.title}}">

<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
<a class="button button-clear" ng-click="sharePost()"><i class="icon ion-share"></i></a>
</ion-nav-buttons>

<ion-content class="has-header">



    <div class="padding">
        <h2 class="title">{{post.title}}</h2>

        <div style="padding:0 0 20px 0;">
        <!-- Posted {{post.date}} by <strong>{{post.author.name}}</strong><br/> -->
        <!-- <em>Modified {{post.modified}}</em> -->
        </div>

        <p ng-show="{{post.attachments.length}}"><img ng-src="{{post.attachments[0].images.full.url}}"/></p>

        <p ng-bind-html="content"></p>

        <p ng-show="{{post.categories.length}}"><i class="icon ion-pricetags"></i>
        <span ng-repeat="category in post.categories">{{category.title}} ({{category.post_count}}){{$last ? '' : ', '}}</span>
        </p>

        <p ng-show="{{post.tags.length}}"><i class="icon ion-pricetags"></i>
        <span ng-repeat="tag in post.tags">{{tag.title}} ({{tag.post_count}}){{$last ? '' : ', '}}</span>
        </p>

        <p><button class="button icon-left ion-share button-outline button-positive" ng-click="sharePost()">Share this</button></p>

        <!-- <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="loadURL(post.url)">
        View post
        </button> -->

    </div>

</ion-content>
```

APP.JS

.factory('PostsData', function($http, $q, PostsStorage, API) {

```
 var json = API + '/api/get_recent_posts/';
var deferred = $q.defer();
var promise = deferred.promise;
var data = [];
var service = {};

service.async = function() {
$http({method: 'GET', url: json, timeout: 5000}).
// this callback will be called asynchronously
// when the response is available.
success(function(d) {
    data = d;
    PostsStorage.save(data);
    deferred.resolve();
}).
// called asynchronously if an error occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
error(function() {
    data = PostsStorage.all();
    deferred.reject();
});

return promise;

};

service.getAll = function() { return data; };

service.get = function(postId) { return data.posts[postId]; };

return service;
```

})

.factory('ServerPostsData', function($http, $q, ServerPostsStorage, API) {

```
var data = [];
var service = {};

/* (For DEMO purposes) Local JSON data */
// var json = 'json/serverposts&';

/* Set your URL as you can see in the following example */
/* NOTE: In case of the default permalinks, you should add '&' at the end of the url */
// var json = 'YourWordpressURL/?json=get_recent_posts&';

/* With user-friendly permalinks configured */
/* NOTE: In case of the user-friendly permalinks, you should add '?' at the end of the url */
var json = API + '/api/jobs/get_job_listing?';

service.getURL = function() { return json; };

service.setData = function(posts) { data = posts; };

service.get = function(serverpostId) { return data[serverpostId]; };

return service;
```

})

COTROLLER.JS

```
// ServerPosts Controller
```

.controller('ServerPostsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicLoading, ServerPostsData, ServerPostsStorage) {
    var data = []
    $scope.posts = [];
    $scope.storage = '';

```
$scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
  template: '<i class="icon ion-loading-c"></i> Loading Data',

  //Will a dark overlay or backdrop cover the entire view
  showBackdrop: false,

  // The delay in showing the indicator
  showDelay: 10
});

$scope.loadData = function () {

    $http({method: 'GET', url: ServerPostsData.getURL() + 'page=' + $scope.page, timeout: 5000}).
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available.
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.more = data.pages !== $scope.page;
        $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(data.posts);
        ServerPostsData.setData($scope.posts);
        ServerPostsStorage.save(data);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }).
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    error(function() {
        $scope.posts = ServerPostsStorage.all().posts;
        ServerPostsData.setData(ServerPostsStorage.all().posts);
        $scope.storage = 'Data from local storage';
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });

};

$scope.showMoreItems = function () {
    $scope.page += 1;
    $ionicLoading.show({
    template: '<i class="icon ion-loading-c"></i> Loading Data',

    //Will a dark overlay or backdrop cover the entire view
    showBackdrop: false,

    // The delay in showing the indicator
    showDelay: 10
    });
    $scope.loadData();
}

$scope.hasMoreItems = function () {
    return $scope.more;
}

$scope.page = 1;
$scope.more = true;
$scope.loadData();
```

})

// ServerPost Controller
.controller('ServerPostCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, ServerPostsData, $sce) {

```
$scope.post = ServerPostsData.get($stateParams.serverpostId);

$scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.post.content);

$scope.loadURL = function (url) {
    //target: The target in which to load the URL, an optional parameter that defaults to _self. (String)
    //_self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.
    //_blank: Opens in the InAppBrowser.
    //_system: Opens in the system's web browser.
    window.open(url,'_blank');
}

$scope.sharePost = function () {

    var subject = $scope.post.title;
    var message = $scope.post.content;
    message = message.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");

    var link = $scope.post.url;

    //Documentation: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin
    //window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message', 'Subject', 'Image', 'Link');
    window.plugins.socialsharing.share(message, subject, null, link);
}
```

})

Comment: did u try storing it in a scope variable and showing it in the DOM ?

Comment: *"How i can do that"* ... Every basic angular tutorial shows you how to do it. Please provide more specific angular code and view html that is causing problems and be more specific about where you have problems

Comment: read this http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withAjax

Comment: @dennyjohn i don't konw what is a scope :)

Comment: @charlietfl the html code pass this, and i want add more information.

`code`
<div class="padding">
            <h2 class="title">{{post.title}}</h2>

            <div style="padding:0 0 20px 0;">
            <!-- Posted {{post.date}} by <strong>{{post.author.name}}</strong><br/> -->
            <!-- <em>Modified {{post.modified}}</em> -->
            </div>

Comment: Can you at least show us your app.js and .html file ?

Comment: @Habkamas i update with html and js thank you

Comment: No controller ? Or controller.js file ?

Comment: @Habkamas added controller.js